# Chromecast, Unblock-Us and Edimax BR-6478AC router

Tags: dns, iptables, chromecast

It seems that Google has hard coded the Google DNS into the Chromecast, thus making it pretty much useless for anyone outside the U.S. who wants to use it for Netflix and Hulu.

I have the above router and I can't flash it with OpenWrt/DD-WRT due to other limitations. Can anyone think of a way to do something similar to [this](http://support.unblock-us.com/customer/portal/questions/1385727-chromecast)?

Comment: If you don't have the ability to modify the IP tables in your router, the above is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying the following today:

I have a computer (iMac) that is connected to my modem. With the router/modem from my internet provider it's not possible to change the primary and secondary DNS, so I have configured the DNS's on my computer. I can access netflix outside of US via un-block US via my computer.

Now if I do the following:

- I create a hotspot on my computer
- I connect to the internet with my mobile devices via the computer (these mobile devices are not un-block us configured)
- I can access netflix on all these devices

If i do this with chrome cast it doesn't work because the DNS's are "hardcoded". But there has to be a way to circumvent this by using your computer. I know that you can enforce the un-block us DNS's on specific routers. check the following URL - http://stuff.purdon.ca/?page_id=322. If this is the case it's possible to programmatically enforce the un-block us DNS's onto the chrome cast.

the link I provided shows you how to enforce the DNS's using the following command on your routers:

```
 $IPTABLES -A PREROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.10.40 -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 208.122.23.23

 $IPTABLES -A PREROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.10.40 -p udp -d 8.8.4.4 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 208.122.23.22
```

I hope this can provide a first step in finding a solution.